# puppeteer chromium dynamic js content

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium, aws-lambda-puppeteer

Trying to scrape a website trough lambda. It loads fine, loads chromium and puppeteer.

However whenever there should be additional content loaded trough third party JS script. For example a plugin `example.js` renders advertisements to `<div class="advertisments"></div>` that lives in the web content that is triggered by input type. Lets say the behaviour is -

- User types a 2 letters "re" to the input.
- `example.js` loads certain ads to `.advertisments` div.

For some reason my chromium either disallows such things or just ignores it.
My workflow is

```js
const page = await pupBrowser.newPage()
page.goto('example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
const input = await page.$('.someInput')
await input.type('re')
await delay(2000ms)
await page.waitForElement('.advertisments')
```

For some reason my advertisments are empty on lambda puppeteer chromium, on local chrome its working.

My arguments are:

```js
[
  '--allow-running-insecure-content',
  '--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
  '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
  '--disable-component-update',
  '--disable-domain-reliability',
  '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess,IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
  '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
  '--disable-print-preview',
  '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
  '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
  '--disable-speech-api',
  '--disable-web-security',
  '--disk-cache-size=33554432',
  '--enable-features=SharedArrayBuffer',
  '--hide-scrollbars',
  '--ignore-gpu-blocklist',
  '--in-process-gpu',
  '--mute-audio',
  '--no-default-browser-check',
  '--no-first-run',
  '--no-pings',
  '--no-sandbox',
  '--no-zygote',
  '--use-gl=angle',
  '--use-angle=swiftshader',
  '--window-size=1920,1080',
  '--start-maximized'
]
```

Comment: I don't think that's enough to answer. Can you at least share what is the end result of the `<div class="advertisments"></div>` look like? once the ad is done loading. (ideally, share the actual page of course, but at least that) I'm assuming `<div class="advertisments"></div>` was the stub before the ad loaded? Basically, what does before and after look like?

Comment: That could just be normal. In other words maybe they don't want to show ads to AWS datacenter traffic

Comment: The ads are just simple example. The pups job was to analyze if "correct ads" are running trough. But figured out that, it decides that requests from Lamba is a bot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like as commenters suggested, I found out similar reasoning.

Running trough local PC it behaves differently than on lambda. As I've further found out that, simply websites do block traffic from bot's (Considers lambda IP as such).

Simply put, if someone else runs in similar trouble - use puppeteer stealth plugin, otherwise analyze the website.

Since the website Im working with - is hosted on shopify, it seems that there is no simple walk around.